# Trouble Running Lisp Script in Emacs with SBCL

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, slime

I'm encountering an issue when trying to run a Lisp script in Emacs with SBCL. I have the following directory structure:

```
- SBCL: /home/user/.roswell/impls/x86-64/linux/sbcl-bin/2.3.8/bin/sbcl
- Lisp Script : /home/user/src/q1.lisp
- Emacs: - /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/emacs
         - /var/lib/emacsen-common/state/flavor/installed/emacs
```

I load the script in Emacs using Alt-X `load-file` and then provide the full path to the `hello.lisp` file.

Here's the content of my `hello.lisp` file:

```lisp
(defun hello-lisp ()
  (format t "Hello, Lisp!~%"))

(hello-lisp)
```

However, when I attempt to run it, I receive the error message "Wrong type argument: stringp, t." I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, and I'm looking for guidance on how to properly execute Lisp scripts in my environment.

Comment: If you use Slime and it is configured to use "ros run" as inferior-lisp-program, your script runs fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're not using SBCL or Slime at all here. You're using **Emacs** command `load-file`, and loading a file that's interpreted as **Emacs Lisp**, not Common Lisp. That's what `load-file` does.

The error is that Elisp function `format` is different from Common Lisp function `format`. The Elisp function expects a format *string*, not the symbol `t`, as its first argument. Use `C-h f format` to see its description.

Comment: It sounds like they want to read https://slime.common-lisp.dev/doc/html/